# Open pdf in new window with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, pdf, jsreport

I'm developing web application using nodejs and jquery. There is a reporting part in it. When a user sends some data to server using ajax call (Here I use 'get' method for make easing the question), it should send pdf to the client side and should show in a pop up window.

I used **jsreport** for server side for generate reports.

Here is the Node js server code.

```
.get('/testPdf', async function (req, res, next) {

    var htmlNew = '<html> ' +
        '<head> ' +
        '</head> ' +
        '<body> ' +
        '<h2>Hello World</h2>' +
        '</body> ' +
        '</html> ';

    return jsreport.render({
        template: {
            content: htmlNew,
            engine: 'handlebars',
            recipe: 'chrome-pdf'
        },
    }).then((resp) => {
        var data = resp.content;
        res.contentType("application/pdf");
        res.send(data);
    });
})
```

This is the code of client jquery.

```
function myPdfRun() {
    console.log('Call')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/testPdf",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (response) {

            window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(response));

        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Err');
        }
    });
}
```

I try few things for doing my task. Below codes executed inside of *success* in ajax call.

**Try 1**

```
window.open("data:application/pdf," + response);
```

//It was open new tab and it is blank.

**Try 2**

Using download js,

```
download.bind(response, "mydownload.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

//Nothing happen. Only success trigger.

**Try 3**

```
download(response, "mydownload.pdf", "application/pdf;base64");
```

//Pdf is downloaded. But content is not there. Just white sheet appears.

**Try 4**

(This code got from a forum)

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64," + response;
a.download = 'export.pdf';
a.type = 'application/pdf';
a.href = pdfAsDataUri;
a.click();
```

A pdf file is downloaded. But cannot even open it.

**Try 5**

```
window.open("data:application/pdf," + response);
```

//open new window. But there is a error log in console window.

Error : *Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:application/pdf,%PDF-1.4%0A%.................*

The best part is, when I call to the Node js api directly (*http://localhost:9176/api/dashboard/testPdf*) from the browser, it is successfully open the pdf. It means there is no problem in server side or return information.

Please show me a direction to open pdf in new window using Ajax call.

Answer (score 8):

## php

```
$base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('YOUR PDF FILE')));

echo $base64 ;
```

## java script

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href= "data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+response;
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = 'filename.pdf';
a.click();
```